# how UI language is changed?

Tags: c#, mvvm, localization

Here, I have a bit confusion about UI language. If language is changed then what happens? The whole folder gets changed or Culture gets loaded? I cannot get what is actually happening.

```
  Properties.Strings.MainWindow_Language_Selection_English_Label="English"
  Properties.Strings.MainWindow_Language_Selection_Gujarati_Label="ગુજરાતી"
```

Please explain what is happening.

```
  private void LanguageSelection_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBoxItem item = LanguageSelection.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;
        if (item.Content.ToString() == Properties.Strings.MainWindow_Language_Selection_English_Label)
        {
            CultureManager.UICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en");
        }
        else if (item.Content.ToString() == Properties.Strings.MainWindow_Language_Selection_Gujarati_Label)
        {
            CultureManager.UICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("gu");
        }

        Settings.Default["UILanguage"] = CultureManager.UICulture.Name;
        Settings.Default.Save();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, setting the culture on application thread will be effective on the next form that is displayed, so to make this work you probably need a login/language selection window where you set the main thread's culture and then show application's main window.

There were a few attempts around this to make language selection take effect immadiately (easier in WPF) but this is how it works out of the box.

In WPF, however, if you are directly binding UI elements to resources you can make the UI update by raising a property change event on your resource property. The easiest way to achieve this (other than creating a new code generator for the .resx file) would be to wrap your resources in a model class like this:

```
public class StringRes : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate {};

    public string Login
    {
        get { return Properties.Strings.Login; }
    }

    public string Password
    {
        get { return Properties.Strings.Password; }
    }

    public void NotifyLanguageChanged()
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Login"));
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Password"));
    }
}

public class MainWindow
{
    private StringRes _resources;

    private void LanguageSelection_SelectionChanged()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = GetCurrentCulture();
        _resources.NotifyLanguageChanged();
    }
}
```

If you have bound your UI elements to the instance of the StringRes class, they will be updated when you raise the notification change event in your model.

Comment: i am using mvvm .it only use in wpf.